# Apache proxypass redirect subdomain to port and path

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, redirect, subdomain, proxypass

Ok, I wasn't sure how to word the title but I'll try to explain my situation.

I have a home server running debian that, among other things, is running "plex media server".

I access my server remotely using a subdomain to a domain I own, lets call it "**mydomain.com**". I access my server on the subdomain "**home.mydomain.com**" (which at the moment just displays some basic html) and I access the "Plex web interface" on "**home.mydomain.com:32400/web**".

What I want to do is redirect the subdomain "**plex.mydomain.com**" to "**home.mydomain.com:32400/web**" for easier access to the "plex interface".

---

I've managed to get halfway there but I'm unsure on how to proceed, or if this is in fact possible to do.

These is my virtual hosts as of now:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName home.mydomain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/home.mydomain.com/public_html

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName plex.mydomain.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:32400/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:32400/
</VirtualHost>
```

Which allows me to access the plex interface at "**plex.mydomain.com/web**", but I still want to get rid of the "**/web**" part.

So to do that I tried:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:32400/web
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:32400/web
```

Which didn't work at all, that just gives my "404 Not Found".

---

So, can this be solved in the way I want? And if so, how do I do it.

Any help is much appreaciated.

Comment: in the local machine where webserver is configured, you can try wget http://localhost:32400/web

Comment: The problem might be a missing trailing slash after web because overall your syntax looks correct. i.e. `ProxyPass / http://localhost:32400/web/`

Comment: @HBruijn No, I tried that. I still get 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of the web context using a rewrite rule:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:32400/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:32400/

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Plex-Device} ^$
RewriteRule ^/$ /web/$1 [R,L]
```

Note the rewrite conditions in the second section.

FYI, I got these settings from here: http://matt.coneybeare.me/how-to-map-plex-media-server-to-your-home-domain/

You should check that out for all the nitty gritty details.  Of particular note would be setting up some basic authentication to protect your host.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the altered solution:

Add a DNAT rule to redirect all traffic from 80 to 32400.

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d X.X.X.X--dport 80 -J DNAT --to-destination X.X.X.X:32400
```

So it would look something like this:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.1 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1:32400
```

Remember your firewall rules:

```
    iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 32400 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

And save your firewall rules:

```
    service iptables save
```

Comment: Maybe I was unclear in my description. The process which run the "plex media server" is already lsitening on port 32400, I can't set apache to listen to it aswell. "plex media server" is completely separate from Apache.

Comment: Then adding a vhost reverse proxy Is not a viable solution. As you have pointed out, the port is already being used.

I am editing my first solution to be your solution.